# android JSON from Url

Tags: java, android, json, spring, intellij-idea

So I am trying to retrieve JSON object from url.
And I cannot retrieve anything from url.
So to test why, I tried the same code on Spring application, and it works just fine.
It crashes on code below only on android environment. 
Please help

```
    package com.example.sandbox;

    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;

    import java.io.*;
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.nio.charset.Charset;

    private static String readAll(Reader rd) throws IOException {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                int cp;
                while ((cp = rd.read()) != -1) {
                    sb.append((char) cp);
                }
                return sb.toString();
            }

            public JSONObject readJsonFromUrl(String url) throws IOException, JSONException {
                InputStream is = new URL(url).openStream();
                try {
                    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
                    String jsonText = readAll(rd);
                    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonText);
                    return json;
                } finally {
                    is.close();
                }
            }











    }
```

Comment: can u post url? or json data itself?

Comment: Can you post some more code and logcat?

Comment: whats the error? and where? pls post it.

Comment: http://hashserver.cloudapp.net:8080/HashValueServer/appHash/1

Comment: I hope you are not reading the url content from the main thread, post code where you are reading it

Comment: Do you have INTERNET permission in the AndroidManifest.xml ?

Comment: I do have     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
in the AndroidManifest.xml if this is the right way to do it

Comment: So I on main thread, on a button onClick method I am only calling readJsonFromUrl(http://hashserver.cloudapp.net:8080/HashValueServer/appHash/1) and it crashes. readJsonFromUrl method is located in different class.

Answer (score 1):

Please check your internet connection and also check if you have added permission for INTERNET in your app's manifest that might be issue. 
what error do you get exactly ?

Comment: and I do have <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> this on the manifest.xml

Comment: @user2857160 ERROR 103 : It seems there is network issue please check with other connection.

Comment: so after having readAll and readJsonFromUrl method provided above, all im doing is                                                    JSONObject json = null;
        try {
            json = readJsonFromUrl("http://hashserver.cloudapp.net:8080/HashValueServer/appHash/1");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }

Comment: See sourcecode of hostconnection of android you might get idea. [Error in android source code](https://android.googlesource.com/device/generic/goldfish/+/master/opengl/system/OpenglSystemCommon/HostConnection.cpp) and check for `Failed to connect to host (TcpStream)` error